# Does the no-hair theorem apply to non-stationary spacetimes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reissner-nordstrom-metric, kerr-newman-metric, no-hair-theorem

Carroll (pg. 238) gives the follow statement of the no-hair theorem:

> Stationary, asymptotically flat black hole solutions to general relativity coupled to electromagnetism that are nonsingular outside the event horizon are fully characterized by the parameters of mass, electric and magnetic charge, and angular momentum.

This makes sense to me; all kinds of different initial conditions all settle down to a much smaller space of final asymptotic states.

But the [Wikipedia page on the no-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) doesn't mention any requirement of stationarity. (A minor section in the page does suddenly start talking about "stable" black holes, but doesn't explain whether "stable" means stationary.)

The theorem seems to be clearly false for non-stationary spacetimes; certainly a black hole formed by dynamical collapse will send out all kinds of anisotropic gravitational radiation and so on. Is the Wikipedia page just wrong, or is there a generalization of Carroll's version of the no-hair theorem that does not require stationarity?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5255892/